# Question based on error propagation.

Tags: error-propagation

If weight of body in air is $w_1=8.00\pm 0.05N$ and weigh in water is $w_2=6.00\pm 0.05N$, then relative density $\rho=\frac{w_1}{w_1-w_2}$ with max permissible error is?

I solved by doing the following, although it’s probably wrong 
$$\frac{\Delta \rho}{\rho}=\frac{\Delta w_1}{w_1}+\frac{\Delta(w_1-w_2)}{w_1-w_2}$$

Plugging in the values we end up with 
$$=\frac{0.05}{8}+\frac{0.1}{2}$$
I took $\Delta (w_1-w_2)$ and $0.05+0.05=0.1$ and $w_1-w_2=8-6=2$
Calculating I get the final value as $\frac{0.45}{8}$. The options are not matching. The correct answer is $4.00\pm 5.62$%

Comment: What is $0.45/8$ ? Nothing is wrong in your solution except that you need to convert the $0.45/8=0.05625$.

Comment: $0.45/8 = 5.625\%$

Comment: We need to find the relative density with max. permissible error, i.e., $\rho \pm \Delta\rho$. You've correctly found $\Delta\rho$, just use that in $\%$

Comment: Woah, didn’t realise that. My bad, and thanks for helping me. I can be too self doubting for my own good.